# SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.ApplicationUsers'

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When displaying the `AspNetUser.Email` from my `Customer` view I get this error.  I am doing a `.Include(AspNetUser)` on the `CustomerController` and referencing the database table name `AspNetUser` where `Email` is coming from.  Not sure what I'm missing here but I need to be able to call `AspNetUser.Email` from the `Customer` view.

My`ApplicationUser` comes from my `IdentityModel` which I have included below.

In my `Customer` table I have a `Customer.UserId` column which is a foreign key to the `AspNetUser.Id` column.

**Customer Model**

```
namespace DemoPool.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    [Table("Customer")]
    public partial class Customer
    {
        [StringLength(128)]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Customer Controller**

```
// GET: Customers
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, User")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var customers = db.Customers.Include(c => c.AspNetUser);
            return View(customers.ToList());

        }
```

**Customer View**

```
@model IEnumerable<DemoPool.Models.Customer>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>               
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AspNetUser.Email)
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**IdentityModel**

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace DemoPool.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DemoPoolEntities", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your entity for ApplicationUser, this is a sql error that the table does not exist

Comment: Yes, I just added it.  ApplicationUser doesn't exist in my db. So should I change Application User : IdentityUser to AspNetUser : IdentityUser? @VidmantasBlazevicius

Comment: By specifying `[ForeignKey]` attribute on a virtual property in your Customer class you are basically telling EF that you have a DB table for it and that the relation will be resolved. If I understand this problem correctly, then you need AspNetUser entity class for this to work.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you.

Comment: You're very much welcome, I posted it as an answer then.

Comment: Marked as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By specifying `[ForeignKey]` attribute on a virtual property in your `Customer` class you are basically telling EF that you have a DB table for it and that the relation will be resolved. If I understand this problem correctly, then you need `AspNetUser` entity class for this to work.